# Array not assignable

Tags: c++, arrays, comma-operator

I wanted to assign a boolean value to a two-dimensional boolean array, but the compiler showed an error

```
bool Amass[100][80];

Amass[1,1] = true; //even so I see only an error
```

Comment: `Amass[1][1] = true;`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `Amass[1,1]` should be `Amass[1][1]`

Comment: Please provide error messages (verbatim) as part of your question. `Amass[1,1]` is not how multidimensional arrays are indexed in C++. Correct is `Amass[1][1] = true;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a two-dimensional array

```
bool Amass[100][80];
```

However in this statement

```
Amass[1,1] = true;
```

in the subscript operator expression you are using the comma operator. Its result is the right-most operand. That is the statement is equivalent to

```
Amass[1] = true;
```

So in the left side of the assignment there is used a one-dimensional array.

It seems you mean

```
Amass[1][1] = true;
```